# Passing Data and go from VC tab index 4 to VC tab index 2

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, segue

I wish to pass data and go from `Search VC` (tab index 4) to `Classes VC` (tab index 2) when I click on the Search Button. `Search VC` is embedded in a `Tab View Controller`. `Classes VC` is embedded in both a `Tab View Controller` and a `Navigation Controller`. See the attached pic.

[image: Pics]

I have tried using seague on the following code, but I lost my `Tab Bar`

## Assuming I created a seague called `SearchToClass` from `Search VC` to `Classes VC`

```
#import "Search.h"    
#import "Classes.h"
#import "ClassNavigationController.h"

@interface Search(){

    NSString *sURL;
}

@end

@implementation Search

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (IBAction)btnSearch:(UIButton *)sender {

NSLog(@"This is the slider %@", lblStart.text);
sURL = @"&Start=";
sURL = [sURL stringByAppendingString:sStartTime];
sURL = [sURL stringByAppendingString:@"&End="];
sURL = [sURL stringByAppendingString:sEndTime];

[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SearhToClass" sender:self];

//======== I have also tried the following but couldn't pass the data and I lost the Tab Bar as well======================================
//ClassNavigationController *fromSearch =  (ClassNavigationController*)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Classes"];
//[fromSearch setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];
//[self presentViewController:fromSearch animated:NO completion:nil];
//===================================================================
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    Classes *target = segue.destinationViewController;

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"SearchToClass"]) {
    
        NSLog(@" To ClassesDet sURL : %@", sURL);
        target.urlFromSearch = sURL;
    }
 }
 @end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you can do. If you want data to be passed from search vc to classes vc.

1. Add notification observer in classes vc

> ```
> NotificationCenter.default
>                 .addObserver(forName:NSNotification
>                     .Name(rawValue: "testKey"),
>                              object:nil, queue:nil, using: yourMethodToBeCalled) //set notification observer
> ```

2. When you have searched for the item and want to pass it to classes vc

> ```
> NotificationCenter.default
>             .post(name: NSNotification
>                 .Name(rawValue: "testKey"),
>                   object: nil, userInfo: ["myData": true, "myList": myList])
> ```

3. Change to tab
   `self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 2`

   **Note: No need for a segue when you are using a tab bar controller**

Comment: How to direct to the Classes VC?

Comment: your ClassesVC at index 2 right so here is the code to do that self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 2 //this is the index

Comment: How do I pass my `sURL` to `Classes VC`. How do I receive the `sURL` at `Classes VC`

Comment: I think you don't have an idea about NSNotifications maybe read a tutorial first so things become a bit clear for you. I already wrote the code above here is how you can pass 

NotificationCenter.default
            .post(name: NSNotification
                .Name(rawValue: "testKey"),
                  object: nil, userInfo: ["myData": sURL ])

Comment: As the classes vc is already set up with an observer in viewDidLoad so as soon as you post something it will be received in classesVC. Then you need to do the step 3 just to change the view and go to classesVC.